# speed on after()

Tags: jquery

To insert a li after #first_li with a certain speed, I do :

```
$("#first_li").after("<li>Hello</li>").fadeIn(500);
```

The insertion works but not the speed, what's is the problem ?

Comment: Which element do you want to `fadeIn`? The `#first_li`, the `<li>Hello</li>`, or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the `li` element to be invisible before adding it to the DOM:

```
$("#first_li").after("<li style='display: none;'>Hello</li>").next().fadeIn(500);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hDzAS/

This selects the `#first_li` element, inserts the hidden `li` element after it, then selects the newly added `li` element and fades it in.

You can also add the `li` element to the DOM like this (if you don't like to concoct strings of HTML):

```
$("#first_li").after($("<li />").text('Hello').css('display', 'none')).next().fadeIn(500);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hDzAS/2/

Docs for `.next()`: http://api.jquery.com/next

### Update

I personally like the `slideDown()` effect: http://jsfiddle.net/hDzAS/1/

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Only the hide() solution works. $("#first_li").after("<li>Hello</li>").next().hide().slideDown(500);

Comment: The examples I posted above all seem to work for me. I tested them in several browsers (IE8, Safari 5, Firefox 9, Chrome 15, Opera 11). `hide()` is just a short-cut for `.css('display', 'none')`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
$("<li>Hello</li>").appendTo("#first_li").hide().fadeIn(500);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dYkf3/1/)**

Comment: `.appendTo($("#first_li"))` -> `.appendTo("#first_li")`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the inserted element starts in a hidden state:

```
$("#first_li").after("<li style='visibility:hidden;'>Hello</li>").fadeIn(500);
```

or

```
$("#first_li").after("<li>Hello</li>").hide().fadeIn(500);
```

Comment: The `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` functions rely on `display : none`, if you set `visibility : hidden` and run `fadeIn` on the element it will still be hidden because the function does not alter the `visibility` property.